# Query to get data from relating tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have 3 tables.

**galery_images**:

- id        | int (primari key)
- image     | varchar (the link on the server)
- tartalom  | longtext
- galery    | int
- order     | int

**galery**:

- id        | int (primari key)
- name      | varchar
- tartalom  | longtext

1-n relation with the images

**galery_category**:

- id        | int (primari key)
- name      | varchar

n-1 relation with the galeries

I'm asking for an image, then I would like to fetch all the relevant data in a single query. I need all the columns, aka, 1 image, 1 galery, and all the categories.

I'm using codeigniter, so I would also like to know what I'm facing while retrieving the categories.

Comment: Typo alert: it's a **gallery** - with **two** "l" in the middle ...

Comment: what are your primary keys?

Comment: No typos involved that is the way I was writing the table names
And, yeah you're right, I did forget to add the primari keys, altough the asnwer down there is satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `galery` is linking column between `galery_images` and `galery` table and `name` is linking column between `galery` and `galery_category` table, you can use the following query.

```
SELECT gi.image, gi.tartalom, gi.galery, gi.order, g.tartalom, gc.name
FROM galery_images gi JOIN galery g ON gi.galery = g.name
JOIN galery_category gc ON g.name = gc.name
WHERE gi.image = ? //Other conditions
```

Please note that it will return multiple records for same image because of 1-many relationship.